# tfx.components.StatisticsGen display train and eval in two different figures, is it possible to have them in a single figure as tfdv does?

Tags: kubeflow, tfx, tensorflow-data-validation

a superimposed display for train/val splits using `StatisticsGen`

Hi,

I'm currently using tfx pipeline inside kubeflow. I struggle to have `StatisticsGen` showing a single graph with train and validation splits curves superimposed, allowing better comparaison distributions. this is exactly how `tfdv.visualize_statistics(lhs_statistics=train_stats, rhs_statistics=eval_stats, lhs_name='train', rhs_name='eval')` behaves (see illustration [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EO5h.png)), and I would like `StatisticsGen` to also provide a superimposed splits graph.

Thanks for any reference or help so that i can move forward.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
# docs-infra: no-execute
# Compare evaluation data with training data
tfdv.visualize_statistics(lhs_statistics=eval_stats, rhs_statistics=train_stats,
                          lhs_name='EVAL_DATASET', rhs_name='TRAIN_DATASET')
```

From the tensorflow data validation tutorial